# "That was a nice waited pass"

Tags: adjectives

In soccer, if a player waits for another player to get into a proper position before passing the ball to him then can I say "That was a nicely waited pass" or would that be grammatically correct?

Comment: Your question seems to imply that you can only say things that are grammatically incorrect. I would not suggest using that as a guide in how to speak any language.

Comment: This is a jargon issue with respect to soccer.  Listening to a British commentator, I would not be at all surprised to hear "That was a nicely waited pass", even though it's not something I'd expect to hear on (US) NBC sports.  But I don't know British sports jargon, so I have no idea whether it's normal usage in the UK or not.

Comment: (I mean, think about it -- does "Two down and 8 to go" make any sense?)

Comment: @LittleEva He just referred to the nicely weighted pass after which he clarified about the well-timed pass too...which is why I thought both answers were fantastic..However I have no problem in selecting your answer too :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A phrase which **is** used in British English is **nicely-weighted pass** — that is, a pass which has just the right amount of weight (effort put in) to get it to exactly where it's needed.

I believe that the OP has heard this, an interpreted the preparation for this kick as a wait.

The phrase "nicely waited pass," however grammatically correct it might be, would be misunderstood as "nicely weighted", and I wouldn't recommend it. If the wait prior to kicking is important, then the pass is **well-timed.**

Answer (score 3):

```
                      "if a player waits ... before passing the ball"
```

Parth, your statement is **not** grammatically **incorrect** and I believe I understand the sports play you are describing. In common American English, using a description of a similar American football scenario, what you said would be more commonly expressed something like this:

**Wow, that was a "*well-timed*" pass.**

***or***

**The quarterback "*patiently waited*" for his wide receiver to get open, and then "*timed*" his (or, *her*) throw perfectly!** (*we use our hands in 'football' -- go figure.*)

***or***

**Did you notice how that running back "*waited patiently*" for his blockers to open a running lane?**

*Thanks jb*

Comment: this should be a comment as it has no relation to the question.  also, a well-timed pass is not a waited pass.

Comment: @JoeBlow - It could be. 'Waited pass' is a logical subset of 'well-timed pass'.

Comment: +1, "well-timed" pass- I believe that's what the OP was waiting for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have heard the phrase 'weighted pass' and misinterpreted its origin. A nicely weighted pass is when the player gives the just right about of *weight* or momentum to the ball, so that the ball is easy for the receiver to control or run onto.

http://www.soccer-training-methods.com/weighted-pass.html

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely normal in English to make almost anything, in to an adjective.

So yeah, you could 100% use the phrase "waited pass" - it sounds great.

I can't see any reason at all that "waited" could not be used as an adjective; there are any number of similar formulations.